# Lista de inicialização de membros com atributos de outra classe (herança)

Tags: c++, classes, construtor, atributos, inicialização

Eu sei que uma lista de inicialização de membros declara e no mesmo instante inicializa um tal atributo(s), é isso oque sei até agora.

No seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout


class Foo {
public:
    const int intNum;
};


class Bar: public Foo {
public:
    Bar( int x ): IntNum( x ) {}
};


int main()
{
    Bar bar( 1 );
    
    std :: cout << bar.intNum << "\n";
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Eu estava tentando inicializar o atributo `intNum` que passou a pertencer a classe `Bar` por ter herdado de `Foo`, então se `intVar` passou a ser de `Bar` porquê houve erro ao tentar inicializar?
Oque tem de errado no código?

Answer (score 0):

Qual o erro? Isso seria importante incluir na pergunta.

Vejo que você declarou intNum com "i" minúsculo na classe-pai, mas está tentando inicializar IntNum (com "I" maiúsculo) na classe-filha.